# stories progress bar is showing me only last picture of my arraylist which coming from firebase database

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, progress-bar

**Stories progress class**
How can I show all my pictures in arraylist coming from firebase as it is displaying only last picture on storyprogressbar .Arraylist contains all pictures Url.problem is not displaying all images on storiesProgressbar .. please help me sorting out the problem.

Here is my firebase tree from where I am getting data(pictures) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EjLz.png)

> DetailStatusActivity

```
 public class DetailStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StoriesProgressView.StoriesListener {


    StoriesProgressView storiesProgressView;
    ImageView image;

    int counter = 0;
    long pressTime = 0L;
    long limit = 500L;

    public View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    storiesProgressView.pause();
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    storiesProgressView.resume();
                    return limit < now - pressTime;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    private String currentUserID;
    private DatabaseReference statusRef;
    private String visit_id;

    private DatabaseReference detailStatusRef;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesArray;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_status);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        storiesProgressView = (StoriesProgressView) findViewById(R.id.stories);


        visit_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        Log.d("cominghereId", visit_id);

        currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        statusRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Statuses");
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        detailStatusRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        View reverse = findViewById(R.id.reverse);
        reverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                storiesProgressView.reverse();

            }
        });
        reverse.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

        View skip = findViewById(R.id.skip);
        skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                storiesProgressView.skip();
            }
        });

        skip.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        imagesArray=new ArrayList<>();

        detailStatusRef.child("DetailStatusesImages").child(visit_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                imagesArray.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DetailStatusModel Dupload = snapshot.getValue(DetailStatusModel.class);

                    imagesArray.add(Dupload.getImage());

                }
                Log.d("sizee", String.valueOf(imagesArray.size()));


                storiesProgressView.setStoriesCount(imagesArray.size());
                storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(3000L);
                storiesProgressView.setStoriesListener(DetailStatusActivity.this);
                storiesProgressView.startStories(counter);

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imagesArray.get(counter)).into(image);


            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onNext() {

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imagesArray.get(++counter)).into(image);
        Log.d("indexx", imagesArray.get(counter));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrev() {

        if ((counter - 1) < 0) return;

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imagesArray.get(--counter)).into(image);

}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

        finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {


        storiesProgressView.destroy();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        storiesProgressView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        storiesProgressView.resume();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5S3xxMHSPo&ab_channel=EDMTDev) might help you

Comment: i have follwed that video but i will show all pictures for the first time..when restart my app i will not show any pic